# Xcode 11: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode11

I have searched many times but didn't find any solution for xcode 11 while building ios app from my react native app.

Please suggest any solution.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/tanzeel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/autodeals-famghlzaemprcbvrzxrehaeaqyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth`
ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code -1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing this exact error and noticed that the '-L-L/Users/...' looked odd because it should only be one -L.

I don't know the source yet, but when I looked at the complete compile command (it begins with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -isysroot .....`) I noticed that there was an empty '-L' in the command so that it said `-L -L/Users/trflagg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...`

Removing this from the command and running that command in the command line got me past this error.

UPDATE:  Removing `$(inherited)` from the Library Search Paths seems to have worked.  However, I don't know the implications of this.

UPDATE 2: Even better, you can just move `$(inherited)` to the bottom of your list of search paths. After figuring this out myself, I then found this answer: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/36#issuecomment-611516268