# React Native 0.64.0 iOS Build Error `ld: library not found for -lAppAuth`

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've been stuck on this a few days now, trying to build my RN project for iOS and facing the error.

```
ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here are the things I have tried so far, that have not worked:

- Currently opening .xcworkspace file in XCode to run build from, not .xcodeproj
- Build cleaned, with `pod clean` run as well as `pod cache clear --all`
- Project Build Settings > Library Search Paths > currently contains:
  `"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`
  `"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`
  `"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods"`
- Modified Build Phases to include the `libAppAuth.a` library like this
  [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrGxO.png)
- Changed settings of `Build Active Architecture` to No in Build Settings
- I've checked and the `-L-L` problem faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409358/xcode-11-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-in) does not occur. In fact,very little info is being specified on what the issue may be in the erroring, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9auV6.jpg)
- I have tried this on both the old and new build system

Will appreciate any help that can be given. Thanks. I'm stuck being unable to develop my iOS RN build at the moment. Both the XCode build and the React Native build are failing